# Is there any way of pulling a class's members into your namespace with "using"?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, using

I'm in a situation where I need to refer to one class in another, and I am constantly doing `SomeClass::` this and whatever. Is there any way to do something similar to `using namespace` but for a class?

I've tried:

```
using MyClass; // Namespace qualified name is required.
using MyClass::; // Expected an identifier
using namespace MyClass; // Name must be a namespace name
using namespace MyClass::; // Name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name
```

I know one of the newer features in C++ is inheriting base class features, like `using BaseClass::BaseClass`, there seems to be a lot of ways to use `using`.  I was wondering if I can do this class thing? Actually, it may just be a good idea to use a namespace instead of a class, if it's completely static.

Comment: Depending on how many types your are dealing with, you could simply create individual aliases for each type you need. `using type = MyClass::type;`.

Comment: No, there isn't. Class is a type not a namespace. If you are looking to mirror some C# behavior with partial classes then you should probably resist the temptation. If you need a namespace then use a namespace.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the context of this question.

Comment: I see, so no other way other than typedeffing each member. OK then. Just trying to keep code short, that's all. I don't know much about C# but it's sounding better and better.

Comment: Bringing in entire namespaces is kinda iffy in general anyways (not just in header files), and can easily become a really bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer,**

No You can't.

**Long Answer:**

Your expressions (with the errors):

```
using MyClass; // Namespace qualified name is required.
using MyClass::; // Expected an identifier
using namespace MyClass; // Name must be a namespace name
using namespace MyClass::; // Name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name
```

:would not work. Yes, of course, one of the jobs of the [scope resolution operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#id.qual) is to make *unqualified-name-lookup* search in certain namespace-scopes. However, to make that same behavior possible for classes (outside the scope of a class or its derived classes), C++ would have to answer **at least** two questions:

- Every name declared within a *class* that is accessed outside it will undergo *access* checking. So in trying to make unqualified name lookup access names in the so-called "class namespace", **how** and **when** should *access* checking be done?
- How do we deal with *non-static members*?

Comment: @Ron, Answer overhauled. Thank you! :-). Please also feel free to edit to answer.